# Webpack v4 with multiple entries on a single page, chunks are duplicated unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, node-modules, webpack-4

I have a multipage website with a subset of pages that is a SPA. We just upgraded to Webpack V4 and have encountered some new issues that we havent seen before.

Our pages *always* include a script tag for **app.build.js**. This file has global inits, and imports our public path. It imports things like Modernizr and builds our site navigation.

Additionally, on a per-page basis we serve a second JS file like **account.build.js**. Some pages do not have this second file if they are very simple. They still need app.build.js to create the navigation though.

It appears as though Webpack doesn't know about this combination, so there are redundant chunks in the two output files. they both may include a Modernizr test, etc. and all of that gets added to both build files bloating them significantly.

My question is, how do you tell Webpack that **app.build.js** is globally included??? We do this with SplitChunks for our vendors, but it matches on imports, not on the entry file name.

We also now need to `import './public-path';` in every entry file, which isn't ideal. I would prefer to do it once in **app.build.js** and have it globally recognized.

Bug filed with Webpack here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8842

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Certainly, here it is: https://gist.github.com/lostPixels/fef3f0cc4a3e99bf526249c605c2096f

Comment: Did you find an answer then @lostPixels ?

Comment: Still no answer I suppose by looking at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10537?

Comment: Nope, no answers so far from Sorka.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all duplicates to a single file (`commons.js`) leaving aside all
vendor files in `vendors.js` you can specify multiple cache groups. This `commons.js`
will contain all modules duplicated across all of your entry points.

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendors: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendors',
        chunks: 'all'
      },
      commons: {
        name: 'commons',
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 2,
        enforce: true,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we tried this and it doesn't catch chunks that are included in two entry files that are paired together in one HTML document.